# Laravel 4: How to make Auth component use a custom ID from the users table

Tags: laravel

At the moment the Auth component uses the **ID** from the **"users"** table whenever referring to the user, i would like to change that to a Custom ID.

For example i have a new column in the users table which is named "**user_unique_id**" it's a varchar type.

How do i make the Auth component is this column instead of the ID column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it on your User model (not Auth)

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface { 

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_unique_id';

}
```